# custom rendering for text in Nebula NatTable cells

Tags: java, swt, nattable

I've developed an SWT application whose GUI includes a NatTable for displaying data read from a database table. The whole GUI is aligned from right, and the problem is that table items including non-alphanumeric characters are not rendered properly. For example, the interval [1,3) is rendered as (3,1]. As another example, xx** is rendered as **xx. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please share further details about what you mean with "right aligned" and how you achieve this.

Comment: I\v used shell.setOrientation(SWT.RIGHT_TO_LEFT); to change the orientation of the GUI

Comment: But that does only change the layout to RTL. Why should it change the content that is rendered? NatTable takes the data out of the `IDataProvider` and renders it as is. It does not convert the data based on such settings. If the content is not shown as you intend, you did something wrong at that level. NatTable is not responsible here. Where do you convert your data from right to left?